# Salesforce Email logging on custom object

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

could really use some serious help on this. Below is the current business case:

1. We have the standard accounts, contacts, and opportunities objects. We've also created a custom object, and let's call it 'Customers.'
2. As of now, 'customers' are related to accounts.
3. Our users have einstein activity capture on, so all the email interactions get logged to the 'Account' level that the contact is related to, which makes sense.
4. The problem is that I want those emails tracked on the 'Customer' activity feed too, not just the 'Account' or 'Contact' activity feed.

Will creating a junction object between contacts and customers allow this activity to be shown in the 'customer' field? Or is there a simpler way to do this? Thank you in advance as this is a major roadblock I am facing right now.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with Einstein Activity Capture yet. What does it save stuff as? `EmailMessage`? `Task`? Either allows adding custom fields so you could add lookup to your `Customer__c`. With Task it's even simpler, it has that mutant lookup thing, Customer should appear as available option if it has "Allow Activities" ticked in setup.

Assuming that gives you something - next step would be to maybe make a custom quick action with some fields prepopulated, maybe a trigger to go "up" to Account and then to Customer(s)... Because out of the box

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aac_limitations.htm&type=5

> Custom objects aren’t supported. When emails are sent from a custom
> object, the email is logged on the activity timeline of the associated
> contact.

You can upvote an idea: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000EAIiQAO

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, Einstein Activity Capture doesn't allow any fields that I could add, since it's not logged as an EmailMessage or a Task.

Let's say I'm not using Einstein...is there any easier way to set up a user so that their emails with Salesforce contacts are logged as tasks or email message? Because then I think this would work perfectly.

Comment: You could try Outlook plugin if you haven't done it already (I'm under impression they're kind of leaving it as is and the future is EAC though). Or mail stuff out of Salesforce rather than Outlook so user would attach them nicely. Or keep using Outlook/what have you but with hidden (BCC) email that sends it to SF and have Apex class to handle them? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_using.htm